# Understanding use of pointer in embedded system

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

Here is a part of the code:

```
#define GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R  ((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025000)
#define LED_BLUE 0x04
#define LED_GREEN 0x08
#define LED_RED 0x02

GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R[LED_BLUE | LED_GREEN | LED_RED] = (LED_GREEN | LED_RED)
```

With my the little understanding I have about pointers, it is equivalent to

```
volatile unsigned long *p = 0x40025400;
p[0x0E] = 0x0A;
```

If I am correct, what does p[0x0E] mean or do here?

Comment: Most likely, this code doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @Lundin, the code might be using [bit-banding](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/CHDJHIDF.html)

Comment: Bit-banding does not make this code any more plausible. Maybe it was invented for the question and is not real. Setting Bit-15 of port F to  0x0A is nonsense.

Comment: This code uses bit-banding to set bits 1, 2, and 3 (mask of 0x0E) to the value of 0x0A.  In other words, it sets bits 1 and 3, clears bit 2, and leaves bit 0 and bits 4-7 unchanged.

Comment: Sorry, I just came to realize that this is NOT bit-banding.  I recognize the code from TI's Tiva C Launchpad.  TI's ARM Cortex-M4 device implements and array of 256 GPIO data registers, which allow you to manipulate individual GPIO bits without doing a read-modify-write-operation.  Address bits 2-9 act as a mask when writing the GPIO Data.  So the code is doing what I described in my previous comment.  But it is not technically bit-banding.  It's a TI GPIO feature with a purpose that is similar to the purpose of bit-banding (i.e., bit manipulation while avoiding read-modify-writes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the indexing operator `[]` has the following semantics: `a[b]` means `*(a + b)`, so either `a` *or* `b` must evaluate to an address.

Thus, your example means `*(0x40025400 + 0xe) = 0xa`, i.e. it accesses a register which is at offset 0xe * `sizeof (unsigned long)` from the base address at 0x40025400. The scaling is since the pointer is to `unsigned long`, and pointer arithmetic is always scaled by the size of the type being pointed at.

Comment: The example in fact means `*((unsigned long*)(0x40025400 + (0xe * sizeof(unsigned long)))`.  The offset is type dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Lundin. The defines `LED_BLUE, LED_GREEN, LED_RED` all being powers of 2 and LED control typically needing only a bit on or off imply that these defines are *bit* masks.

Suggest you need the following.

```
void LED_Red_On(void) {
  *GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R |= LED_RED;
}

void LED_Green_Off(void) {
  *GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R &= ~((unnsigned long)LED_GREEN);
}

...
```